# SugarCRM CE 6.5 Calculation Not working

Tags: php, logic, crm, sugarcrm

Need help getting calculations to work.  I have the following code

crm/custom/modules/Leads/logic_hooks.php

```
<?php
// Do not store anything in this file that is not part of the array or the hook     version.  This file will    
// be automatically rebuilt in the future. 

$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
// position, file, function 
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array(1,'Calculating field',    'custom/modules/Leads/custom_comm.php','calculate_field_class', 'calculate_field_function');  
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Leads push feed', 'modules/Leads/SugarFeeds/LeadFeed.php','LeadFeed', 'pushFeed'); 
$hook_array['after_retrieve'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_retrieve'] = Array(1, 'calculating commission', 'custom/modules/Leads/custom_comm.php','calculate_field_class', 'calculate_field_function');
$hook_array['after_ui_frame'] = Array(); 



?>
```

crm/custom/modules/Leads/custom_comm.php

```
<?php
Class calculate_field_class
{
 function calculate_field_function()
  {
  $bean->commission_c = $bean->vehicle_gross_c / 2;
   }
}  
die("I got called")
?>
```

These do not work at all.  Any suggestions.  I have hit all the forums and searched the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass into the method the bean object, current event and any arguments. Also, be careful not to reset the array in the logic hook.

**custom/modules/Leads/custom_comm.php**

```
<?php
    class calculate_field_class {
        public function calculate_field_function($bean, $event, $arguments) {
            $bean->commission_c = $bean->vehicle_gross_c / 2;
        }
    }
?>
```

**custom/modules/Leads/logic_hooks.php**

```
<?php
    $hook_version = 1;
    $hook_array = Array();
    // position, file, function
    $hook_array['before_save'] = Array();
    $hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Calculating field', 'custom/modules/Leads/custom_comm.php', 'calculate_field_class', 'calculate_field_function');  
?>
```

Comment: oh ok so just add public and should be good. Ill give that a try

Comment: Yeah that still does not work.  Not sure where to go from here

Comment: No, pass in $bean, $event, $arguments into your method and pay close attention to the structure of things in logic_hooks.php.